# Android: apk size increases when I generate signed build

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-build, android-install-apk

[image]If I generate a build normally in my android studio, it generates an apk with a size but when I generate signed apk for the same code it increases apk size?

In my case unsigned apk size is 7856 kb and for signed apk it's 8680 kb. It's increased by 824 kb, Why?

Comment: use studio's apk analyzer tool (double click on your apk from studio output folder) to check what happen

Comment: I checked with apk analyser tool it's showing max diff. in res folder. Why it is adding more resources? Please check added image in answer.

Comment: please post gradle

Answer (score 1):

Android adds few files to the build by itself...it also merges few manifest files to the build in order for it to be recognisable as a release build. You can get a better idea of exactly what and how large things are added to your apk , by analysing your normal build apk and release apk with the APK analyser tool in studio 2.2+

Keeping  minifyEnabled true , would help you reduce your apk file size,if you need to

Comment: I checked, please check updated question with apk analyser difference image. Why res folder size increases this much for signed build?